# CS50 caesar doesn't exit after non-numeric input

Tags: c, return, exit, cs50, caesar-cipher

I'm getting an error that the program times out while waiting for program to exit after it handles a non-numeric key.  I can't see where the problem is.

This is the part of the code where I think the problem is:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); i < n; i++)
        if(isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: %s\n", argv[0]);
            return 1;
        }
```

It works correctly if more than one argument is entered in the command line, but it doesn't exit if an alpha key is entered.

Comment: isalpha(argv[1][i]) will return non-zero if the input character is alphabet. Otherwise, it will return 0. So, your `if case` will never be executed. I am not sure if this is the root cause.

Comment: The code shown is not reading any input, but only checks that the first command-line argument is present and doesn't contain any alphabet characters. It is not clear if by "non-numeric key" you mean a keypress, but if so, this is not where the error is. Try to reduce your code down to the minimal amount that still reproduces the error.

Comment: Also, pay attention to correct indentation and put the `for` loop body in `{ }`.